# Object Declaration in Task<>[] Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll

Tags: c#-4.0

```
   var t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => test<Employee>());
    var t2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => test<Customer>());
    var t3 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => test<Order>());

    Task[] tasks = new Task[] { t1, t2, t3 };

    var resultx = Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(tasks, (task) =>
    {
        Task.WaitAll();
        task[0]// Result is missing, I don't see Result in the intellisense.
    }
   );
```

It appears that if i mention the datatype in the `Task<T>` task only then i'm able to see the "Result" pop up in the intellisense like `task[0].Result`.Why is that so? .
Each test method returns a `IEnumerable<T>` object of type passed as a generic item.Infact, all the objects that i pass to `test<T>()` inherits from a base class "Company".Basically an abstract factory pattern.Am i missing something?

Answer (score 4):

The base [`Task`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx) class does not have a Result property.  That property is defined on [`Task<TResult>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321424.aspx), which is a subclass of `Task`.  If `test<T>()` returns an `IEnumerable<T>`, then t1, t2, and t3 are of type `Task<IEnumerable<Employee>>`, `Task<IEnumerable<Customer>>`, and `Task<IEnumerable<Order>>`.  Since these are all subclasses of `Task`, it's perfectly legal to add them to an array of `Task`.  You are then calling the overload of `ContinueWhenAll` that takes an array of `Task` objects, so you will not be able to use methods on `Task<TResult>`.

If Employee, Customer, and Order all inherit from Company then you could instead create an array of `Task<IEnumerable<Company>>` objects and use the overload of `ContinueWhenAll` that takes an array of `Task<TResult>`.

You won't be able to cast `Task<IEnumerabl<Employee>>` to `Task<IEnumerable<Company>>` since `Task` is not covariant, but you could create them as `Task<IEnumerable<Company>>` in the first place.

Something like this:

```
var t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew<IEnumerable<Company>>(() => test<Employee>());
var t2 = Task.Factory.StartNew<IEnumerable<Company>>(() => test<Customer>());
var t3 = Task.Factory.StartNew<IEnumerable<Company>>(() => test<Order>());

var tasks = new Task<IEnumerable<Company>>[] { t1, t2, t3 };

var resultx = Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(tasks, (task) =>
{
    IEnumerable<Company> result = task[0].Result;
});
```

Another option is to use the t1, t2, and t3 variables directly rather than using the task parameter.  The task parameter is going to contain the same objects as the original tasks array, so you could just do:

```
var resultx = Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(tasks, (task) =>
{
    IEnumerable<Employee> result = t1.Result;
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response but i inherited all the sub classes from Company just to have a common parent so that i can map the result the way you suggested Task.Factory.StartNew<IEnumerable<Company>>(() => test<Order>());
But unfortunately "Company" is just a dummy class with no methods.Rest all the classes has meaningful methods that returns IEnumerable<T>. I didnt have an option except to be more specific like IEnumerable<Employee> result = t1.Result; There are 14 different classes like Employee and no way i can make them Generic :-(

Comment: @Princeton: I think I'm misunderstanding something.  In your original question, you have a variable t1 that is a `Task<IEnumerable<Employee>>`.  Are you trying to get a reference to the `IEnumerable<Employee>` in the lambda you pass into ContinueWhenAll?  If you are, then you should be able to just use `t1.Result` as I said in the last part of my answer.  Does that not work, or is that not what you're trying to do?